# disable SSL from home page only with.htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, ssl

i want to switch the home page only of my website from https to http,i need to know how to do it using htaccess file.
i've tried so many options and nothing worked, Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Put this in the `.htaccess` file in your document root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=302,L,NE]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`